# Windows 8.1 Sony Vaio Flip making Chirping sounds and 100% Disk Usage

Tags: windows, windows-8, laptop, sony-vaio

I just bought a Sony Vaio Flip from Best Buy (SVF15N17CXB)

http://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=SVF15N17CXB

Since i acquired the laptop the performance in general has been very poor, menus are sluggish, programs and games randomly freeze every 5 -10 minutes or when they start an action. I tried the Setting custom page file usage to 8GB and max to 16GB and that didn't work.

When i study the task manager, the only issue that is constantly happening is the 100% Disk usage, RAM, CPU, network occasionally spike up but never reach maximum utilization.

Also every so often i hear a chirping sound that goes off about 3-5 times randomly without any real pattern. Not sure if this has something to do with it.

What do you guys think the problem is?

**EDIT:** After doing some sleuthing around i discovered there is an option in the Vaio control panel called Hard Disk Protection. This option will limit HDD activity if the sensors detect abnormal movement, when detected, it makes a sound to let you know its working(The Chirping). Since i have my Flip setup like a tripod(My favorite feature) it was invoking the hard drive protection option. After turning this off, performance has gone up immensely and the chirping sound has gone away forever.

I was still having some performance issues (Not 100% disk, just typing and sluggish menus still) and i came across Throttle Stop.

http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/2288/throttlestop-6-00/

This has also improved performance as well, although the computer is still a bit sluggish. Although beware this can cause your computer temperature to rise above what it was designated to causing issues such as your computer freezing/locking up. I purchased a laptop cooling pad which has eliminated the locking/freezing issues when using Throttle Stop.

Comment: Sounds like a busted HDD, but with the little information provided it's impossible for us to say for sure.  Do SMART checks on your drive.  Do disk checks on your drive (chkdsk).  Try a different, known-good HDD.

Comment: You should absolutely exchange it within the return policy. The chirping sound is most likely the drive head. When you receive the new one, uninstall any unnecessary programs and stop any extraneous startup items.

Comment: The chirping ended up being a  built in sound to let users know Hard Disk Protection was being activated.